# How do you apply Core Image filters to an onscreen image using Swift/MacOS or iOS and Core Image

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-image

Photos editing adjustments provides a realtime view of the applied adjustments as they are applied.  I wasn't able to find any samples of how you do this.  All the examples seems to show that you apply the filters through a pipeline of sorts and then take the resulting image and update the screen with the result.  See code below.

Photos seems to show the adjustment applied to the onscreen image.  How do they achieve this?

```
func editImage(inputImage: CGImage) {
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
            let beginImage = CIImage(cgImage: inputImage)
            
            guard let exposureOutput = self.exposureFilter(beginImage, ev: self.brightness) else {
                return
            }
            guard let vibranceOutput = self.vibranceFilter(exposureOutput, amount: self.vibranceAmount) else {
                return
            }
            guard let unsharpMaskOutput = self.unsharpMaskFilter(vibranceOutput, intensity: self.unsharpMaskIntensity, radius: self.unsharpMaskRadius) else {
                return
            }
            guard let sharpnessOutput = self.sharpenFilter(unsharpMaskOutput, sharpness: self.unsharpMaskIntensity) else {
                return
            }
            
            if let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(sharpnessOutput, from: vibranceOutput.extent) {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cgImage = cgimg
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: "How do they achieve this?"  What is 'this'?  You mean, making the resulting effect permanent?

Comment: This is achieve realtime updates to the image showing the applied effects - btw I think I found the answer - MTKView and using the draw() function to render the image as the effects are applied.  Kind of have it working but the image is not filling the entire view - so I guess I have to work out the metal coordinate system and how to scale the image to fit the view.  It's never as easy as they make it sound !

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just found the answer - use MTKView, which is working fine except for getting the image to fill the view correctly!

For the benefit of others here are the basics...  I have yet to figure out how to position the image correctly in the view - but I can see the filter applied in realtime!

```
  class ViewController: NSViewController, MTKViewDelegate {
        
        ....
      @objc dynamic var cgImage: CGImage? {
            didSet {
                if let cgimg = cgImage {
                    
                ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
    
                }
            }
        }
        var ciImage: CIImage?    
    
            // Metal resources
            var device: MTLDevice!
            var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
            var sourceTexture: MTLTexture!                         // 2
            let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            var context: CIContext!
            var textureLoader: MTKTextureLoader!
            
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
        
           // Do view setup here.
                let metalView = MTKView()
                
                metalView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                self.imageView.addSubview(metalView)
               
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    metalView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
                    metalView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                    metalView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                    metalView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
                ])
                
                device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()            
                commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()
                
                metalView.delegate = self
                metalView.device = device
                metalView.framebufferOnly = false
                
                context = CIContext()
                
                textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device) 
    
         }
        
           public func draw(in view: MTKView) {
            if let ciImage = self.ciImage  {
                if let currentDrawable = view.currentDrawable {              
                    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()
                    
                    let inputImage = ciImage     // 2
                    exposureFilter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                    exposureFilter.setValue(ev, forKey: kCIInputEVKey)
                    
                    context.render(exposureFilter.outputImage!,                      
                                   to: currentDrawable.texture,
                                   commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                                   bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: view.drawableSize),
                                   colorSpace: colorSpace)
                    
                    commandBuffer?.present(currentDrawable)                
                    commandBuffer?.commit()
                }
            }
        }
```